# Using absolute paths in PHP not working

Tags: php

I am trying to use absolute paths to get a definitive reference to a config file.
For this, I am currently doing this:

```
require_once '../config.php'; //Works fine
```

But when I try this:

```
require_once '/config.php'; //Throws error, see below
```

The error I get is:

> require_once(): Failed opening required '/config.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear')

Is this a thing in PHP 5.6.0 or am I missing something?

Comment: Shouldn't you use ./config.php?

Comment: @TomaszTurkowski, same error, just with a dot in front of the 'config.php' part, error as follows: **require_once(): Failed opening required './config.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear')**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Breaking down `../config.php`:

1. `../` goes one directory *above* the **working directory**
2. `config.php` finds the file `config.php` in that directory

Breaking down `/config.php`:

1. `/` goes to the ***server*** root
2. `config.php` finds the file `config.php` in that directory

If the first one works but not the second, it means that the file `config.php` is *not* in the root folder, but is in the parent directory of the working file.

Comment: `config.php` **is** in the root folder for this, I made sure of that

Comment: @SamSwift웃 The root folder of your website or the root folder of your server ?

Comment: I am running localhost, `C:/xampp/htdocs/config.php`, then the rest is in `C:/xampp/htdocs/{site_name}/`

Comment: In that case... `C:/xampp/` would be in the root folder I believe. `/config.php` would find `C:/xampp/config.php`

Comment: I shall try that now then

Comment: @SamSwift웃 So your config.php is not in the root folder, the root folder in your case is `C:/`

Comment: The root folder for xampp via the `httpd.conf` file is `C:/xampp/htdocs`, this is the root folder

Comment: Try listing the files in the root directory using something like `print_r(scandir("/"));` and see which directory it is?

Comment: if config.php at root file then remove / from your code. ex : require_once 'config.php'; //Throws error, see below

Answer (score 0):

If you explicitly set the includes path in your script to the actual location it should be quite simple to include the files you need such as:

```
set_include_path( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
require_once( 'config.php' );
```